# Inheriting from BasePage class

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I was wandering how could I achieve scenario:

I have class PageBase where I have OnNavigatedTo,OnNavigatedFrom,BackPressed behaviour but no view (or just popups if it's possible). And then how do I inherit from this class in my MainPage - I get error:

> partial decralatcion of page must not specify (...)

For me important is that all the pages look differenlty but some behaviour is simmilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides inheriting from the base class, you also need to update your XAML.

```
<local:PageBase xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                .......
```